# inbuilt Function that will return Sum of positive number.?

Tags: c++, stl

I have an array and i want stl function that can return Sum of positive and sum of negative number.

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <functional>   
#include <numeric>     

int myfunction (int x, int y) 
{
    if(y>0){
        return x+y;
    }
}



int main () {
int init = 0;
int numbers[] = {5,10,20,-34,56,-67,-32,16};


std::cout << "using custom function: ";
std::cout << std::accumulate (numbers, numbers+8, init, myfunction);
std::cout << '\n';


}
```

output is coming garbage value.

using custom function: 4196215

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "*sum of negative number*" I don't think I understand this correctly. You can just take the sum of negative numbers. Your snippet doesn't reflect your intention, you should get a warning that not all code paths are returning a value. Are you perhaps looking for `abs()`?

Comment: `myfunction` fails to `return` if `y<=0`. You must never reach the end of a function body before reaching a `return`, unless your function returns `void` or is `main`.

Comment: I am getting garbage value "using custom function: 4196215 ". i am trying only sum of positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your "output is coming garbage value" is that when `y <= 0` you return some garbage value (i.e, no return statement).

```
int myfunction (int x, int y) 
{
    if(y>0){
        return x+y;
    }

    // <<== you need to return something here, too
}
```

I would say `return x` in that case, but that won't work for arrays where the first element is `<= 0`

Comment: Why won't it work if the first element is zero or less?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something along these lines:

```
int myfunction (int x, int y) 
{
  return x + std::max(y, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a function has a return type different thatn `void` in its signature then you need to make sure it **always** (unless some exceptional event occurs) return some value no matter which path you take during the execution.

Your function fails to do that as when `y<=0` you return nothing.

You can fix it doing something like the following:

```
int myfunction (int x, int y) 
{
    if(y>0)
        return x+y;
    return x;
}
```